# Need help deciding about regression or appropriate statistic

Tags: regression, spss

I need to check if presence/absence of repetitions on a verbal test occur due to frequency of external distractions, frequency of self-distractions, or a count of words spoken from original word to the repetition word. There are also scores of general cognition, education years and gender which could be considered as probable contributing factors.

Update: I did a binomial logistic regression first. The DV was 1 and 0 coding for presence/absence of repetition (across three groups), and the IV was separate counts of self and external distractions, education yrs, overall cognitive score. Now my professor would like me to analyze, among those had repetitions (for three groups), can we check which of the factors contributes most towards repetition: 1.words between original word and repetition, 2.internal distrators, 3.external distractors, and education (not necessary).

Could some please let me know the next possible steps?

Comment: Please ask one question at a time (pick 1. or 2.) And describe the problem and the data in detail: how is the data collected, what do the covariates represent, what is the outcome variable and how is it measured.... If you can include (a sample of) the data, all the better.

Comment: Thank you. For example, I need to check if repetitions on a verbal test occur due to frequency of external distractions, frequency of self-distractions, or a count of words spoken from original word to the repetition word. There are also scores of general cognition, education years and gender which could be considered as probable contributing factors. How should I go about with my analysis?

Comment: Please edit the body of your question, as not everyone reads the comments. (And again -- the clearer, the better.) Thanks.

Comment: Thank you. Done.

Answer (score 1):

Summarizing: Your dependent variable is "number of repetitins" and your independent variables are different kinds of distractions, demographic factors, and so on.

First, you say "due to".  You can only attribute causality from regression if you did a true experiment. That is, if you (or the researcher) controlled the number and type of distraction and you have random assignment and so on. If this is based on observational data (that is, you just observed what happened, then you can only talk about association, not causation.

It does sound like you need some kind of regression, the question is which kind. The number of repetitions is a count - a non-negative integer. You don't say much about it, but it seems likely that it is a relatively small count. That would indicate that some sort of count regression model is appropriate. The simplest of these is Poisson regression, but its assumptions are rarely met (I've never had a case where they were met, but they do exist). More likely you need negative binomial regression, but (if there a lot of cases with 0 repetitions) you might need a zero adjusted variation of one of these.

Also, you say you have a lot of other independent variables. This raises its own set of issues, including model building/variable selection and possible collinearity. Both of these have been discussed a lot here and elsewhere.

Comment: Please don't do "Allow me to explain a bit more" in a comment -- edit your question to provide all relevant info. That only gets you an answer full of guesses like this one.

Comment: See e.g. http://www.dmstat1.com/res/PredictiveContributionCoefficient.html  and also search for articles on "variable importance".  LASSO regression may be useful.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response Peter. I did a binomial logistic regression first. The DV had 1 and coding for presence/absence of repetition (across three groups), and the IV was separate counts of self and external distractions, education yrs, overall cognitive score. Now my professor would like me to analyze, among those had repetitions (for three groups), can we check which of the factors contributes most towards repetition: 1.words between original word and repetition, 2.internal distrators, 3.external distractors, and education (not necessary).